# Need Google Drive APIs Client Library code running samples

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, android-googleapiclient

We need full access of users Google drive, but it's providing limited access. We are unable to find Google APIs Client Library samples. Attached linked provide following information for samples.

[From the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth)

> The Google Drive Android API currently only supports drive.file and drive.appfolder authorization scopes. If your application requires additional permissions or features not yet available in the Drive Android API, you must use the Google APIs Java Client.

Where can I find Google APIs Java Client documentation and samples?

Comment: Have you tried checking the documentation for each of the methods in the drive api?  Most of them have java examples. https://developers.google.com/drive/v2

Comment: Each drive method documentation page has a Java tab which shows the library usage

Answer (score 1):

The [GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro) API you're referring to is an API build on top of the [REST](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk) API and supports only FILE scope.

The REST API supports the DRIVE scope that allows access to all folders/files.

I can offer a very simple DEMO of basic CRUD functionality for the [REST API here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo) (and parallel version of the [GDAA API here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo)).

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more than the drive.file and drive.appfolder scope offer for your android application then you will need to use the [API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v2) instead of the Google Drive Android API available in Google Play Services.

You will also need the [Google APIs Client Library for Java](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client) which performs common REST API tasks including authentication and token management. Review the "The library runs on Android (@Beta)" section in the README to see how to retrieve a Drive service object on android.